# How to record audio from browser and upload to django server?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have to record an audio from the browser and upload it to the django server, can someone help me?

My django view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def audio_analysis(request):
    audio_data = request.FILES['audio']

    # view content

    return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

Comment: To record audio, you need to create an audio stream. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API

Answer (score 0):

You can upload recorded audio from browser by this javascript code

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true})
.then(stream => {
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
mediaRecorder.start();
const audioChunks = [];

mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
  audioChunks.push(event.data);
});

mediaRecorder.onstop = function(){
    const file = new File(audioChunks,'filename.mp3');
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", file);
    fetch('your url',{
        method:"POST",
        body:form
    })
}
setTimeout(function(){
    mediaRecorder.stop();
},3000)});
```